# Number of sites is different on SE homepage and SE sites

Tags: bug

When you scroll over the Stack Exchange symbol in the top left corner of every SE site page, it tells you the total number of sites on the SE network. For some reason this number is 138 on any SE site (or at least the ones I've checked this on), but 140 on the SE homepage (the page with the hot questions).

Here it is on the SE homepage:

[image: 140 sites]

Here it is on Meta (also on SO, Lifehack, Worldbuilding, and Puzzling, and probably other sites too)

[image: 138 sites]

I checked the [tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) on SE and it says 137 sites. Obviously there's some bug here. I haven't counted the sites (too lazy) but I've been told that it is actually 138. I'm not really sure why it's happening, but this may confuse some people.

Comment: Don't hold your breath... it can be catching.

Comment: If you count the sites on SE homepage, they are actually 138!

Comment: (the numbers have changed drastically, but the underlying reason is basically the same)

Comment: @jonsca The person who asked that counted the questions manually and compared it to another unknown source. Also his wasn't a bug because it shouldn't have counted MSO or stack apps. Here I have 3 sources all from SE and they are all different. It is related but I do not think it is a duplicate.

Comment: (but the crux of it is that they are counting MSE and Stack Apps in one statistic and not the other)

Comment: @jonsca Oh that second post is definitely the same

Comment: No worries :), I knew it had been asked before multiple times.